# How to uniquely identify and fetch children objects in JDO

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I am just learning JDO and GAE, and have gotten myself very stuck on this.

I have gone from having just

```
public class Article {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    ...
}
```

To now also having a parent:

```
public class ArticleCollection {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    private Key key;
    private long count
    private Set<Article> articles;
}
```

However after doing this, the following code to fetch an article by id no longer works. How do I uniquely identify an object?

```
Article article = (Article)pm.getObjectById(KeyFactory.createKey(Article.class.getName(), id));
```

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A child's key includes information about its parent.  You need to use a KeyFactory method that includes the parent ID.

```
createKey(Key parent, java.lang.String kind, long id)
          Creates a new Key with the provided parent from its kind and ID.
```

Check out the [javadoc](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/KeyFactory.html) for more details.  There is also a Builder class for convenience that lets you do something like:

```
Key key = new Builder("ArticleCollection", 123).addChild("Article", 1424).getKey();
```

That form becomes more useful as your hierarchy grows deeper, because you can chain a bunch of `addChild`s together before calling `getKey`.

If you don't know the parent of an article, I think you're stuck doing a GQL query rather than a get by key.